# How should I be declaring "stuff" in C++?

Tags: c++

What is the best looking and meaningful way to declare an array?

For an example:

```
char *chData[ 100 ];
char chLetter;
```

The "ch" in both declared variables stands for "char". However,
one is declared as an array. How should I be delcaring that?
Should I be declaring it like this:

```
char* a_chData[ 100 ];
char chLetter;
```

The "a" in variable "a_chData" stands for array. Looks good
right? Yes it was until it was declared in a class:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    char*   m_a_chData[ 100 ];
    char    m_chLetter;
};
```

The "m" in variable "m_a_chData" stands for member because it
was declared as a member of a class which is ClassA. But,
it doesn't look good.

Oh, how should I be declaring a class? Should I declare it like this:

```
class cParent
{
};
```

The first "c" in "cParent" stands for class. Should I just forget about the "c" and just leave it as "Parent"?

Comment: Drop `type[fixed_length]` and use either `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: That's the hungarian notation and with modern IDEs it's largely obsolete.

Comment: It is up to you to choose a nomenclature for your variables. At least if there is no firm policy for it. Only thing: choose one and stick to it.

Comment: @Burkhard Yeah I know. But, I couldn't think of a way to declare an array.

Comment: Take Burkhard's advice seriously. ___Choose one and stick to it.___ Nothing is worse than having to remember whether a member starts with `_`, `m_`, `m`, `<nothing>` or has a certain suffix. Don't even bother to include the type to your variable - sometimes you change the type later into something different (e.g. `short` to `int`, or a built-in type to a custom class) and then you would need to change __all__ occurrences.

Comment: @Zeta I did took his suggestion seriously. Does anyone have a suggestion for me on how to declare an array?? If I declare a char variable, I would use "ch" in front. But, I am stuck with char array. I mean I can just declare a char array the same way I declare char. I thought there would be a "way" of declaring an array.

Comment: @Zeta "sometimes you change the type later into something different (e.g. short to int, or a built-in type to a custom class) and then you would need to change all occurrences" Hmmm, good reason. + 1

Comment: You will probably get a different answer from everyone you ask, it is largely personal preference. I would recommend following the style that your group is already using, or if you aren't coding with a group, use whatever makes sense to you. Personally, I find it more useful to use a name that is plural for arrays and singular for a single variable. I wouldn't include the type as most IDEs can tell you, and t could change later anyway.

Comment: @CLearner: at my work, arrays are prefixed by a `p`.

Comment: @Alex Yeah you are right. I guess I'll just forget about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, if you follow this path you'll end up with some really unwieldy names.

Naming is largely up to preference (for personal or new projects) or convention (for existing projects). If you want to go learn a convention, read some code that you might want to contribute to.

Most importantly, though, be consistent with your naming scheme. Readability counts -- whether for yourself, or for others. Being consistent means that people can figure out your naming scheme and understand your code easier.

And, if you find your naming convention is constraining you, drop it. Nothing is worse than a naming convention that is unnatural -- it will slow you down and make it harder for you to write effective code. Once you've learned a naming convention, it should flow naturally.

Comment: "Being consistent means that people can figure out your naming scheme and understand your code easier" exactly + 1.